# Pdoc - Change template directory programatically

Tags: python, documentation, pdoc

I have a script that generates documentation using pdoc for all of my classes in my project. I want to further customize my documentation by making changes to pdoc templates. I want to do this inside of my project so I can track changes in git, therefor I need to change --template-dir. This is easy enough as a cmd line argument but I have not been able to make this change when using pdoc inside a python script. My question is where can I pass in this argument and or if I make an object of pdoc is there a function or parameter to make this change. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#custom-templates) says:

> If working with pdoc programmatically, *prepend* the directory with modified templates into the `directories` list of the [`tpl_lookup`](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/doc/pdoc/#pdoc.tpl_lookup) object.

This is the [object in question](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/6cfbc4fa0f09de79c51aedb435707a4dcd3b01b9/pdoc/__init__.py#L54-L64) so something like this should work:

```
import pdoc

pdoc.tpl_lookup.directories.insert(0, MY_TEMPLATE_DIR)
```

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I have looked at this part of the documentation and just over looked that! Thank you so much, I can verify this works.